# Automating Power BI License Assignment with C#

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi

I'm creating an automated process, so I create a new List item in SharePoint, then I use MS Flow to trigger my API to invite user to my Azure AD organization. **Now I need to assign Power BI license to this new user.**

*Is it possible to assign Power BI license using Power BI API?*

P.S. I found the way to assign PBI license but using PowerShell, but I can't use PowerShell in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [assign license](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_assignlicense) method of MS Graph API might help. Triggering from flow should be possible as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you Krista! :)